# Azure-pipelines: No module named "xmlrunner"

Tags: django, azure-pipelines, python-poetry, python-3.10

There seem to be many "No module names..." on Azure Pipelines issues in Stackoverflow... and now, as none of them helped me, it's my turn :(

This is the pipeline I'm trying to run: a simple CI to test my Django app, based on Microsoft's own template:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python310:
      PYTHON_VERSION: '3.10'
  maxParallel: 2

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(PYTHON_VERSION)'
    architecture: 'x64'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: dotEnv
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'uploaded.env'

- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Export project path'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      """Search all subdirectories for `manage.py`."""
      from glob import iglob
      from os import path
      # Python >= 3.5
      manage_py = next(iglob(path.join('**', 'manage.py'), recursive=True), None)
      if not manage_py:
          raise SystemExit('Could not find a Django project')
      project_location = path.dirname(path.abspath(manage_py))
      print('Found Django project in', project_location)
      print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectRoot]{}'.format(project_location))

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Add .env file'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: 'uploaded.env'
    TargetFolder: '$(projectRoot)'
  
- script: mv uploaded.env .env
  displayName: 'Rename .env file'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
    python -m pip install poetry
    python -m pip install unittest-xml-reporting xmlrunner
    poetry install
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pushd '$(projectRoot)'
    poetry run python manage.py test --testrunner xmlrunner.extra.djangotestrunner.XMLTestRunner --no-input
    poetry run coverage xml
  displayName: 'Run tests'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: "**/TEST-*.xml"
    testRunTitle: 'Python $(PYTHON_VERSION)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
     codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
     summaryFileLocation: 'coverage.xml'
     reportDirectory: 'htmlcov'
  displayName: 'Publish Coverage Results'
```

This fails on the testing stage, with the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmlrunner'`

The strangest thing to me is that I see `xmlrunner` being installed in the previous steps:

[image]

Has anyone been through this before?

**Edit**: I've recently come across the same problem with a different repo. The issue appeared when I migrated to Poetry and Python 3.10, so one of the 2 might be the culprit.

Comment: Poetry might be the culprit.
I changed the way I installed my requirements to the code below... and it worked!

`- script: |
    poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --dev --without-hashes
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install requirements'`

Answer (score 0):

You're pip-installing both `xmlrunner` and `unittest-xml-reporting`, but all you probably want is `unittest-xml-reporting`.  `xmlrunner` is another PyPi library.

Comment: Thanks, Andy, but it doesn't work. Even with just `unittest-xml-reporting` I still get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmlrunner'` error.

Comment: @OriginalBBQSauce found the solution to your problem?

Comment: Nope... it's still failing :(

Comment: @Seb, were you using poetry? If so, I think I found a workaround.

Comment: @OriginalBBQSauce I'm not using `poetry` no. Uninstallling and reinstalling all the packages had not worked at the beginning because of some discrepancy between what was installed locally and what was used in the repo.